# How to write a regular expression to match a limit of 125 characters per line with an optional delimiter?

Tags: c#, regex

I am making a textarea input box and the user enters a keyword with an option match type like this:

Keyword With Optional Spaces|My Match

The Keyword With Optional Spaces needs to have the limit of 125 characters. If the optional delimiter is entered it needs to either be Broad Match, Exact Match or Phrase match. Does anyone have an example or a similar regular expression? This is probably the toughest one I have delt with.

Thanks,
Darren

Comment: What language are you planning on using? General regex is a huge area.

Comment: Hi this is for use with a C# MVC model validation.

Comment: You're users are ***way*** smarter than my users.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
^[^|]{1,125}(\|Broad Match|Exact Match|Phrase Match)?$

^ begin of string

[^|]{1,125} 1-125 of non-pipe characters

(\|Broad Match|Exact Match|Phrase Match)? An optional | followed by the three "Match" phrases

$ end of string
```

You will need to activate the ignore case (for the `Broad Match|Exact Match|Phrase Match`)

Comment: That is awesome it worked! I believe the ignore case is (?i) for C# I will try this server side.

Comment: Hi thanks, I have modified it to:
^("|\[)?[a-zA-Z0-9']{1,125}("|\])?$
to match [adsads] "tafff" or dadsadsas but how do I make this per line and how would I make it so a [ would require a ] and a " would require an ending "? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{n,m}` to match a set number of characters.

Here is a regex that might accomplish what you would want:

```
^[^|]{1,125}|
```